# PHP Url Root and Absolute Path

Tags: php

I have been stuck on this for a day or two and can't see what the issue is. I have a file called webconfig.php with this code.

```
<?php
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', '/home/es23/htdocs/CIT313/SP2016/a1');
define('URL_ROOT', 'http://corsair.cs.iupui.edu:20151/CIT313/SP2016/a1');
?>
```

In a form I want it to go to this page

```
<form action="<?php echo 'URL_ROOT' . '/add_products_to_inventory.php' ?>"method="post">
```

But when I press the button to proceed to that page I get a Not Found and it says--> The requested URL /CIT313/SP2016/a1/URL_ROOT/add_products_to_inventory.php was not found on this server.

I know the file is on the server but I'm pretty sure the URL_ROOT that is showing in between the a1 and add_products_to_inventory.php is incorrect. Can anyone steer me towards what would be causing this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, when you don't start with a protocol the link assume it's relative to the current path. Your link is not starting with a protocol because you used `'URL_ROOT'` and when surrounding it in quotes like this it becomes a string, not a constant.

```
<form action="<?php echo 'URL_ROOT' . '/add_products_to_inventory.php' ?>"method="post">
```

should be

```
<form action="<?php echo URL_ROOT . '/add_products_to_inventory.php' ?>"method="post">
```

Comment: Notice that even here in SO the syntax highlighting makes `'URL_ROOT'` a red string color, and `URL_ROOT` the black of raw code.

Comment: Thank you I knew it was going to be something simple that I was overlooking.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help. If it was right, click the check mark to signify the answer as accepted. This helps the reputation of Stack Overflow work as it was meant.

Comment: Yea I'm waiting on the timer to go down so I can check it.